# Alternatives for SVMs

Tags: machine-learning

In the disadvantages of SVM [they say](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

> If the number of features is much greater than the number of samples,
>   the method is likely to give poor performances.

What is a good alternative in such case ?

Comment: I think this is a shared problem of machine learning. But you could try doing some dimensionality reduction before learning - like PCA, Sammons mapping or whatever.  btw. shouldn't this question be under math or stats?

Answer (score 3):

You can keep an eye on the [libsvm guide for beginners](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf), in the section C.1 it gives you the answer and an example of exactly what you have asked:

> **C.1 Number of instances << number of features Many microarray data in**
>
> bioinformatics are of this type. We consider the Leukemia data from
>   the LIBSVM data sets (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/
>   datasets). The training and testing sets have 38 and 34 instances,
>   respectively. The number of features is 7,129, much larger than the
>   number of instances. We merge the two les and compare the cross
>   validation accuracy of using the RBF and the linear kernels:
>
> - RBF kernel with parameter selection
>
>   $ cat leu leu.t > leu.combined
>
>   $ python grid.py leu.combined
>
>   ...
>
>   8.0 3.0517578125e-05 97.2222
>
>   (Best C=8.0,   = 0:000030518 with ve-fold cross-validation rate=97.2222%)
> - Linear kernel with parameter selection
>
>   $ python grid.py -log2c -1,2,1 -log2g 1,1,1 -t 0 leu.combined
>
>   ...
>
>   0.5 2.0 98.6111
>
>   (Best C=0.5 with ve-fold cross-validation rate=98.61111%)
>
>   Though grid.py was designed for the RBF kernel, the
>     above way checks various C using the linear kernel (-log2g 1,1,1 sets
>     a dummy  ).
>
> The cross-validation accuracy of using the linear kernel
>   is comparable to that of using the RBF kernel. Apparently, when the
>   number of features is very large, one may not need to map the data.
>
> In addition to LIBSVM, the LIBLINEAR software mentioned below is also
>   effective for data in this case.

So as you can see you can use SVM with linear kernels and obtain good results.